# Pointers to use Apache Drill to access a Progress DB

Tags: business-intelligence, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db, apache-drill

Progress/OpenEdge is not a SQL database and although it does have support for SQL (through the ODBC interface) that is not the natural way to access OpenEdge data.  Progress applications are built using "ABL" (formerly known as "Progress 4gl") and some SQLish things like referential integrity constraints are implemented through procedural logic in 4gl code. Which makes things difficult if you are not really interested in learning ABL.

Has anybody successfully managed to use Apache Drill (https://drill.apache.org) to access Progress data?  Are there any pointers particular to the combination of Progress and Apache Drill to share?

Comment: The usefulness, or lack thereof, of the ODBC/JDBC drivers depends greatly on the application.  It isn't so much the database as it is the way that the programmers decided to put things together.  Some applications are very relationally designed, others were "designed" without any apparent thought to niceties like "3rd normal form".

Comment: @TomBascom maybe having foreign keys and views would help, don't you think? But this is not a thread about Progress apology/dissing so can we please stick to the topic?

Comment: Exactly.  No need to get all snobby about the technology.

Comment: I am just giving a bit of a context: Drill is used mostly to give a convenient, performant, scalable,  unified way to access diverse (mostly NoSQL, Json outputting) datastores. Progress is definitely "NoSQL" but not in the usual sense of the term so I wanted to explain my motives and my goal.

Comment: Are you looking for reporting in general, or just in "Drill"?

Comment: @TimKuehn Personally I'd be open to at least consider different tools but if at all possible make it a comment instead of an answer so that we can stick to the main topic, thanks!

Comment: Go to this link, click on "application type" and then "reporting" https://www.progress.com/partners/partner-directory

Comment: @TimKuehn - done, thanks. Unfortunately I doubt these will be a fit: Progress is the "odd man out" in our current application portfolio, so I don't think we want to invest more into duplicating what other vendors have already delivered for the rest of out landscape (e.g.:Crystal Reports works with basically everything, except Progress). What I hope to find is a _free_ tool that can somehow interface with an existing Progress DB and allow business users to execute queries in a (to them) friendly and intuitive manner. Apache Drill seemed a good candidate.

Comment: Ok - Another option is BIRT - I've seen conference presentations where BIRT was hooked up to a progress db http://www.eclipse.org/birt

Comment: Thanks! I'll investigate this.
Also, I will put up a Bounty as soon as possible, so if anyone wants to ask the same specific question (about Drill) on PEG that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Short answer:* No, this is impossible.

*Longer answer:* my admittedly cursory read of what Apache/Drill does lead to the mistaken conclusion that you can just access Progress (or anything else) via ODBC and then use Drill on top of it.

Apache/Drill is exposing *itself* via ODBC but currently the only datasources it can use are:

- HBase
- Hive
- MapR-DB
- Avro
- Parquet
- File system:

  - CSV (Comma-Separated-Values)
  - TSV (Tab-Separated-Values)
  - PSV (Pipe-Separated-Values)

Therefore at the time being Progress cannot be accessed by Apache/Drill.